# How to design a primefaces datatable with a vertical and horizontal header

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I want to design a datable using primefaces that have a horizontal and a vertical header.

Something like this:

[image: sample datatable]

Is it possible?

Comment: You can decorate first column with header style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by using the **frozen columns** feature. That means you also need to **populate the first column with vertical header text values**.

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtScrollView.cars5}" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150" scrollWidth="300" frozenColumns="1">
    <p:column headerText="Id" footerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Year" footerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Brand" footerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Color" footerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

In this example, the ID column is frozen and can act as a vertical header. Remember for this to work you need to set the `scrollable` attribute to true and you need to set a value for `scrollWidth`.

On top of this, there's another small challenge: the vertical header column will need a horizontal header as well otherwise the rows won't line up. If you do not wish to add such a header then, using CSS, you can set a height to the frozen column header class:

```
th.ui-frozen-column {
     height: 8px !important;
}
```

Adjust the height value based on your needs.

You might also have to play with some CSS if your other columns have an expanded height (after using images or something like that). The frozen row won't expand its height automatically so you'll have to do that manually.

Check the Primefaces site for more info on frozen columns and rows: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml